# Intergrate a non-signed assembly into an existing application

Tags: c#, .net, dll, assembly-signing

I have a problem which I'm pretty sure that I can't solve without going back to the vendor, but I thought I would float the problem here first.

Anyway, I have an assembly from a 3rd party that I have to incorporate into existing applications, but it is not signed. This obviously gives me a load of headaches as all my existing product assemblies are signed, and to reference the new dll from these would require me to not sign them. I really don't want to do that.

Do I have any other options other than a) going back to the vendor to try and get them to sign it or b) not-signing any dll that references it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to ask the vendor for a properly signed assembly.

Failing that, you do have the dirty option of disassembling the assembly with ILDASM, then reassembling it with your own strong name encryption key.  This will require a bit of work.  Talk to the vendor first, and perhaps even mention (not threaten) that you'd rather not have to disassemble their assembly.

Comment: I hadn't considered going to those lengths, and I hope I don't have to! I'll go back to the vendor tomorrow, but considering this DLL is shipped with their commerical product(!!!) I'm not hopeful. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: This called IL round tripping and its actually fairly easy to do. `ildasm yourassembly.dll /out=yourassembly.il` and then 
`ilasm yourassembly.il /res=yourassembly.res /key=yourkey.snk /dll`